# Data cardinality is ambiguous, Make sure all arrays contain the same number of samples

Tags: python, arrays, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

i have file img which every img have different dimension and i put img into list like this

```
files = []
for item in images:
  img_org = nii_reader(item)
  img = sitk.GetArrayFromImage(img_org) # example shape: (9, 40, 43), (6, 46, 45) and more
  files.append(img)

train_files, val_files, train_labels,  val_labels = train_test_split(files, Label, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)
```

and i change the label to categorical like this

```
n_classes = 2
train_label = np_utils.to_categorical(train_labels, n_classes)
val_label = np_utils.to_categorical(val_labels, n_classes)
```

i make cnn model like this

```
model_cnn = keras.Sequential(
    [
        layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation="relu", input_shape=(32, 32, 3)),
        layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
        layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation="relu"),
        layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
        layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation="relu"),
        layers.Flatten(),
        layers.Dense(64, activation="relu"),
        layers.Dense(n_classes, activation="softmax"),
    ]
)
model_cnn.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True), optimizer="adam", metrics=["accuracy"])
model_cnn.fit(train_files, val_files, epochs=5, validation_data=(train_label, val_label))
```

and then i get error in the line model_cnn.fit

```
Data cardinality is ambiguous:
  x sizes: 7, 10, 8, 9, 9, 8, 6, 8, 8, 8, 9, 8, 8, 7, 5, 10, 7, 7, 6, 7, 7, 8, 6, 7, 5, 6, 8, 5, 7, 8, 9, 6, 8, 7, 8, 5, 9, 7, 7, 5, 7, 9, 5, 5, 7, 5, 10, 6, 8, 7, 7, 9, 7, 8, 8, 7, 6, 6, 5, 8, 7, 6, 6, 5, 7, 7, 6
  y sizes: 6, 7, 6, 9, 7, 8, 6, 6, 9, 9, 7, 7, 6, 10, 6, 4, 9, 9, 7, 6, 5, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 6, 8, 6, 7, 7, 5
Make sure all arrays contain the same number of samples.
```

what can i do to fix this error?

Comment: I think your question is answered here, take a look https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/97536

Comment: I think that your code is not a problem, but your dataset is a matter. Did you check the number of the gap between images and labels?

Comment: how do i check the number of the gab ?

Answer (score 0):

Before answering your question, I assume your sample model needs to be like this below. (check out how to use `fit` method, https://keras.io/api/models/model_training_apis/)

```py
# Model construction
model_cnn = keras.Sequential(
    [
        layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation="relu", input_shape=(32, 32, 3)),
        layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
        layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation="relu"),
        layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
        layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation="relu"),
        layers.Flatten(),
        layers.Dense(64, activation="relu"),
        layers.Dense(2, activation="softmax"), # n_classes
    ]
)

# Model compile
model_cnn.compile(
    # outputs are softmax results from one-hot encoded labels, thus not sparse one
    loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=False),
    optimizer="adam",
    metrics=["accuracy"]
)

# (Optional) Visualize model structure and parameters
model_cnn.summary()

# Model train & val
model_cnn.fit(
    # swap `val_files` and `train_label`
    x=train_files,    # `Input data` with shape (train_size,32,32,3)
    y=train_label,    # `Input data labels` with shape (train_size,2)
    epochs=5, 
    batch_size=32,    # If unspecified, batch_size will default to 32
    validation_data=(
        val_files,    # `Valid data` with shape (val_size,32,32,3)
        val_label     # `Valid data labels` with shape (val_size,2)
    )
)
```

However, the model expects to receive images with 32x32 pixels in RGB (3 channels) for example. If you put images with **NOT** in the shape of (32,32,3) as inputs, then the model may throw another error message.